# getting php variable from url

Tags: php, html, xhtml

Is it possible to get php variables from the url?

e.g

test.php contains;

```
     $value1 = 45;
     $value2 = 50
     $value3= 43
```

Would it be possible to retrieve those 3 values only using a URL to the test.php file?

```
       e.g www.test.com/test.php?x=value1?y=value2?z=value3
```

So if a program sent a request of some sort to that url, it would return the 3 values

Comment: Your question seems sort of backwards, or confusing. You're trying to extract the values *from* the file, and send them back to the requesting file? Not set the values within the file from the URL, correct?

Comment: Probably what you should do is have that PHP file print JSON

Comment: So for the confusion. Basically i have an application that cannot process PHP by itself so I will have to using an extension like curl or socket to access the php file and retrieve the information

Comment: What are you retrieving it into? A browser?

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done,
use

```
<?php
$fromurl = $_GET['var'];
?>
```

then in your browser domainorip/yourfile.php?var=something
obviously change domainorip to your server address and yourfile.php to your php document the value will be stored in the $fromurl variable

Answer (score 2):

Why is that hard ?

```
$value1 = $_GET['x']; /"prints" value1
```

or alternatively you can make use of [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: I want to get the values from the url itself if possible. the calling application doesnt do PHP.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want the URL to be returned to your application? Of cause you can do a

```
redirect to test.php?x=value1&y=value2&z=value3
```

whenever there's access to the test.php. But you gonna make sure your application can receive the redirect URL though.

The better way of doing this is actually through SOAP webservice i think, especially if you're going to have more of these communication between PHP and native application.
It can be as simple as something like this in test.php ([`with webservice setup`](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/))

```
function getValues($x)
{
    if(isset($x))
    {
        $result+=$value1;
    }
return $result;
}
```